# Payment plugin for Documents Seller

Tags: php, curl, joomla

I try to build payment plugin fo Joomdonation Documents Seller, i can send order to Bank, pay and after have some problem, when order is created and sent, it has status: in_progress, after payment status changes to success, i try to change record in database with if ($status == success) but can not. here is both files, 1. i start payment

```
    session_start();
    
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    
    class os_bog extends DSFPayment
    {
    public function __construct($params, $config = [])
        {
            parent::__construct($params, $config);
    
        }
    public function processPayment($row, $data)
        {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ipay.ge/opay/api/v1/oauth2/token',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($client_id.':'.$secret_key)),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        $token = $response ['access_token'];
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ipay.ge/opay/api/v1/checkout/orders',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
      "intent": "CAPTURE",
      "items": [
        {
          "amount": "'. $data['amount'].'" ,
          "description":  "'.$data['item_name'].'",        
          "product_id": "'.$data['item_name'].'"
        }
      ],
      "locale": "ka",
      "redirect_url": "https://editor.ge/",
       "shop_order_id": "'. $data['order_number'].'",
      "show_shop_order_id_on_extract": false ,
      "capture_method": "AUTOMATIC",
      "purchase_units": [
        {
          "amount": {
            "currency_code": "GEL",
            "value": "'. $data['amount'].'"  
          }
        }
      ]
    }',
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type:  application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer' . $token  ),
    ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
    
        $payment_hash = $response ['payment_hash'];
        $order_id = $response ['order_id'];
    
        if (isset($response['order_id'])) {
            $payment_hash = $response['payment_hash'];
            $order_id = $response['order_id'];
            $redirect_url = $response['links'][1]['href'];
           header("Location:" . $redirect_url);
        }   
        $_SESSION['order_data'] = array(
        'order_id' => $response ['order_id'],
        'payment_hash' => $response ['payment_hash'],
        );      
     return $response;
        
        }
    public function verifyPayment()
        {
            if ($this->validate())
            {
            
            }
        }
        protected function validate()
        {
            $this->notificationData = $_REQUEST;
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

2. i check status of payment

```
    session_start();
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ipay.ge/opay/api/v1/oauth2/token',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($client_id.':'.$secret_key)),
    ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        $token = $response ['access_token'];
        $order_data = ($_SESSION['order_data']);
        $order_id = $order_data['order_id'];
        $payment_hash = $order_data['payment_hash'];
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ipay.ge/opay/api/v1/checkout/payment/'.$order_id,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type:  application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer' . $token  ),
    ));
    
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
```

p.s. i can not check payment inside plugin(first code), callback url is predefined by Bank and i was no able to put code inside "public function verifyPayment()"
I am far not experienced , could someone help? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: But although i need it for joomla it is not joomla code, in any case if I break the rules, I can delete it :)

Comment: I thought you were saying that you needed help with modifying a Joomla extension.  You are welcome to ask it here.  It is on-topic.  Asking about how to modify a Joomla extension is also on-topic on JSE.  If general PHP knowledge is all that is required, you may receive good support on SO; however, if ANY Joomla knowledge is advantageous, I'd recommend posting on JSE so that you can get feedback/support from people who have a more intimate understanding of the CMS and its extensions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i appreciate it, i posted on JSE as well, as i wrote web page is on joomla but first code has only class of joomla extension and  second one is independent file outside of joomla, so i think here i have more chances to get help